# Type trait for character types in C++?

Tags: c++, char, c++20, type-traits

I'm writing a library function that is capable of processing any integral type, but I would like to prevent it from also processing character types (e.g. `char`, `char16_t`, etc) because it might be confusing to the user (I have a separate function for processing characters that should look like characters).

I'm currently using code like this:

```cpp
template <
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_integral_v<T> && !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, bool> &&
        !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, char> && !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, wchar_t> &&
        !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, char16_t> && !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, char32_t>>>
constexpr auto do_stuff(T curr) noexcept {
    /* TODO */
}
```

However, this seems very brittle - for example, this wouldn't be totally correct on a C++20 compiler with `char8_t`, and even if I did the proper feature tests for `char8_t` it's still rather awkward having to list them all out.

Is there a way to detect char-like types where I wouldn't need to list all of them out?

Comment: No, you have to list them.

Comment: But `char` [**is**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) an integral type.

Comment: I'm aware that `char` is an integral type, but chars are being formatted differently in my library.  Even `<iostream>` treats `char` differently from other integral types...

Comment: @Bernard: So... how would you process 8-bit integers? Because the only one that *isn't* also a character (including `uint8_t`, which can be `unsigned char` which is definitely a character type) is `std::byte`. Which is *not* an integral type.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's an open question.  I could follow `<iostream>` and force users to cast it to `short` or `int` first, or follow @HolyBlackCat's answer and treat `[un]signed char` (but not `char`) as an integral type.  Or maybe have an alternative, more verbose, way to say that we want the argument to be formatted as an integral.  But treating `char` as an integral type seems incongruent with expectations, since my interface also accepts strings.

Comment: @Bernard: C++ is not a language which, at the type system, recognizes a difference between a character and an integer. A character is a *type of integer*. So if you have a system for processing arrays of integers, it therefore is also a system for processing arrays of *characters* (ie: strings). Also, any "array of integer" system should be taking the array size in some way, yes? Whereas strings when taken purely as `char const*` are almost always assumed to be NUL-terminated. So it should be a different interface: one for NUL-terminated strings, and one for sized arrays of integers.

Comment: @NicolBolas Treating `[un]signed char` different from `char` does have precedent in `std::format`, if I'm reading the standard correctly.

Comment: While C++ doesn't recognize at the time system a difference between a character and an integral, in practice `char` (and perhaps `wchar_t`) is almost universally used as characters, while `[un]signed (char|short|int|long)` is almost universally used as integrals.  This means that choosing sensible defaults will be correct in almost all cases, and in those corner cases we could let the user override the default using some more verbose syntax (which is the design of both `<iostream>` and `std::format`).

Comment: I'm not sure what point you're making about `char const*` being null-terminated, but we would choose to treat it as a string because it's a pointer to `char`.

Comment: @Bernard: "*in practice char (and perhaps wchar_t) is almost universally used as characters, while [un]signed (char|short|int|long) is almost universally used as integrals*" Is that true? I personally have seen plenty of C++ code that uses `char` as an 8-bit integer, which uses `char*` as a pointer to an array of bytes rather than characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234482/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-bernard).

Comment: @NicolBolas Why remove the c++17 tag?  This ought to work on C++17, but I also want it to be correct if somebody uses it with C++20.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::make_signed_t<T>> || std::is_same_v<T, std::make_unsigned_t<T>>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr
>
```

This accepts `signed char` and `unsigned char`, while rejecting `char`. `int8_t` is `signed char` on all common standard library implementations (libstdc++, libc++, and the MSVC's one).

Note the unusual double SFINAE. It's necessary because `std::make_[un]signed` causes a hard error if given a non-integral type.

---

Alternatively, in C++20 you could check if `std::cmp_equal` accepts your type. It also rejects `char` and `char*_t`, while allowing `[un]signed char`.

```
requires requires{ std::cmp_equal(T{}, T{}); }
```

Comment: What is the rational for disallowing this to work for `char` (apart from "because the standard says so")?

Comment: It doesn't preclude `signed char` and `unsigned char` though, if I'm reading correctly.

Comment: @Bernard Probably to force people to use `signed char` and `unsigned char` for integers, which makes some sense.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yep. I *think* this is what OP wants.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this requires concepts, it seems to do what I want.  Your comment made me think a bit more - since `char` could be signed or unsigned, my library won't really be able to decide how to properly format it.  But because `signed char` and `unsigned char` exist (and are conventionally used to store small integers), the user can communicate their intent by using those types.   Which then leads to another question - are `std::[u]intX_t` types guaranteed to be non-(`char`|`wchar_t`|`char16_t`|`char32_t`|`char8_t`)?

Comment: @Bernard As sorry, that was a typo. I meant to say that `int8_t == signed char`, on all standard library implementations I tested.

Comment: Ah I see, that's good then (at least in practice).

Comment: Your edit seems to be the most ideal solution, which works also for extended integer types.  Is there somewhere in the standard that mandates the order of detection for double SFINAE?

Comment: @Bernard Can't find a standard quote, but [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) says *"Substitution proceeds in lexical order and stops when a failure is encountered."*, so it should be ok.